# How can I solve this err in javascript?

Tags: javascript

// P5.js ***

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(380, 600);
  player[1]=160
  player[2]=600
  player[0]=new Player(player[1],player[2],0)
 // for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
  //s   walls.push([walls[i-1][2],walls[i-1][3],walls[i-1][2]+random(-50,50),walls[i-1][3]+random(-10,100)])
}
walls=[
[1  ,1  ,100,150],
[100,150,20 ,200],
[20 ,200,220,350],
[220,350,300,450],
[300,450,120,600],
[200,600,380,450],
[380,450,300,350],
[300,350,100,200],
[100,200,180,150],
[180,150,80,0]]
player=[0,0,0]
function draw() {
  background(220);
  player[0].show()
  player[0].update()
  for(var k = 0;k<=walls.length;k++){
    line(walls[k,0],walls[k,1],walls[k,2],walls[k,3])
  }
}

class Player{

    constructor(x,y,z){
        this.x=x
        this.y=y
        this.z=z
        this.dir=(this.z-0.5)**2
    }
    show(){
        rect(this.x,this.y,20,20)
    }
    update(){
        this.x+=this.z
        this.y-=1
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at draw (sketch.js:26)
    at p5._main.default.redraw (p5.js:65953)
    at _draw (p5.js:58869)
draw @ sketch.js:26
_main.default.redraw @ p5.js:65953
_draw @ p5.js:58869
requestAnimationFrame (async)
_draw @ p5.js:58892
requestAnimationFrame (async)
_draw @ p5.js:58892
_start @ p5.js:58740
p5 @ p5.js:59080
_globalInit @ p5.js:58340
load (async)
25.../core/main @ p5.js:58353
o @ p5.js:34
(anonymous) @ p5.js:38
16../color/color_conversion @ p5.js:52829
o @ p5.js:34
r @ p5.js:51
(anonymous) @ p5.js:55
(anonymous) @ p5.js:18
(anonymous) @ p5.js:20
```

Comment: When `draw()` is executed `player[0]` is `undefined`. That extract from your script does not show the relevant parts -> Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: @Andreas Just above the `draw()` is `player=[0,0,0]` so it should be 0, not undefined, right?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be nice as @Andreas suggests. ... Failing that we have an XY problem im afraid.

Comment: I missed how you try to access the elements of the "inner" arrays in `walls`. `walls[k,0]` is not how this works. That combined with the wrong condition in the loop (see Mehdis answer) causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop iterates over one element too much:

The index of he last element in `walls` array is equal to `walls.length-1`. Hence, `k` should be *strictly* lower than `walls.length`.

For loop definition should be changed to:

```
for(var k = 0; k < walls.length;k++){
```

Comment: Are you sure? Will this solve OP's range of problems?

Comment: You might want to also fix the way how OP tries to access the elements of the "inner walls" (which causes the not so obvious `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error)